# Основы многопоточного программирования. Корректное использование Synchronized, wait() и notify() на примере

Tags: java, многопоточность

Решаю задачу, условие которой звучит примерно так: "Есть два потока, один из них считает кол-во времени пройденного с начала сессии, другой поток раз в секунду выводит эту разницу. Необходимо организовать программу так, что бы поток-таймер уведомлял поток вывода. Используйте `wait()` и `notify()`."
Я убрал детали своего кода, оставив лишь конструкции синхронизации. Подскажите пожалуйста, как именно я должен написать свой код, на каком объекте синхронизироваться, когда брать блокировку, когда уведомлять и когда отпускать.

Поток-таймер:

```
 public void run()
 {
    while(true)
    {
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            // высчитываю разницу
        }
    }
 }
```

Поток вывода:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        synchronized(Timer.lock)
        {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getState() == RUNNABLE )
            {
                System.out.println(Timer.differeceInTime);
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {

    }
```

Условие `if (Thread.currentThread().getState() == RUNNABLE)` показывает ошибку, писать `== RUNNABLE`, как я понимаю, не верно. Хотел бы так же узнать, как правильно задавать такое условие ("если поток активен")

Comment: попробуйте добавить в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: А что мешает в одном потоке только модифицировать время, а в другом только считывать его? Никакая синхронизация с блокировками не требуется.

Comment: у current thread просто физически не может быть иного state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включил режим экстрасенса и попытался понять что вы хотите. В итоге получил следующий код.
Для начала, нам нужен класс содержащий результат, которым будут обмениваться потоки. Объект данного класс так же будет и объектом синхронизации. Для корректной работы так же потребовалось добавить поле готовности результата.

```
private static class Result {
    private boolean isReady;
    private long time;
}
```

Так же нам нужен класс создающий этот самый  результат.

```
private static class Producer {
    private final Result result;

    private Producer(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            doSomething();
            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

            synchronized (result) {
                result.time = time;
                result.isReady = true;
                result.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        //сюда нужно вписать операцию время которой вы хотите измерить.
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс для вывода результата выглядеть будет так:

```
private static class Consumer {
    private final Result result;

    private Consumer(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            synchronized (result) {
                while (!result.isReady) {
                    try {
                        result.wait(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(result.time);
                result.isReady = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы запустить всю эту компанию, потребуется создать для объекта каждого класса по потоку.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Result result = new Result();
    Runnable producer = () -> new Producer(result).run();
    Runnable consumer = () -> new Consumer(result).run();

    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(producer);
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(consumer);

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10000);
}
```